# Auto correlation in time series and regression analysis

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, mathematical-statistics, autocorrelation

Why is it necessary to not have auto-correlation in the time series data or in the variables for regression analysis? And how can we check of the auto-correlation in the data?

Comment: 1. It is not necessary. 2. Have you googled it? I am sure there are plenty of answers already.

Answer (score 3):

1. It is not necessary to have auto-correlation in time series data but if you want to use the normal ARMA parametric modeling, both the moving average and the autoregressive processes have some sort of autocorrelation structure.
2. One of the requirements of normal regression is that each observation should be independent of each other. So there should not be any correlation between observations
3. You can check if there is autocorrelation in the data by using a correlogram plot which laggs the data n steps and then check the correlation of original data with the lagged data. For lag = 1, you check the autocorrelation of 1 step and for lag = 2 you check the autocorrelation of 2 steps etc.

Answer (score 2):

You mean to say that the residuals should not have autocorrelation. If you have built a good model that captures the pattern in the data then the residuals will be N.I.I.D.

Comment: Not necessarily N, if by this you mean normality. Other distributions are fine as well. Normality only yields convenient inference in finite samples, nothing more.

Comment: You agree with these statements, right? https://www.google.com/search?q=n.i.i.d.&oq=n.i.i.d.+&aqs=chrome..69i57.6061j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=n.i.i.d.+time+series

Comment: I agree with your answer except that I would not give any weight to normality; any other distribution would do equally well. (Think of a process that is generated by nonnormal i.i.d. shocks; would you try to make them normal? Statistically there is no sound reason for that.) The link you included in the comment does not yield any particular website, just a Google search of "n.i.i.d. time series". What am I supposed to see there?

Comment: The link shows that n.i.i.d is a common used term with time series data. The n stands for "normal".

Comment: OK, I got it. Indeed, people often assume normality even when there is no statstical reason for it (but yes, it is a convenient assumption).